# jQuery plugin question - populate select options with JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, input, plugins

I'm trying to fill selects with json data from a web service.  I'm getting error 'Object doesn't support this property or method.'  when I do this `$(this).html(options.join(''));` 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
;(function($) {

    $.fillSelect = {};

    $.fn.fillSelect = function(url, map) {
        var jsonpUrl = url + "?callback=?";        
        $.getJSON(jsonpUrl, function(d) {
           var options = [];
           var txt = map[0];
           var val = map[1];
           options.push('<option>--Select--</option>');
           $.each(d, function(index, item) {
                options.push('<option value="' + item[val] + '">' + item[txt] + '</option>');
           });
           $(this).html(options.join(''));
           //getting error  Object doesn't support this property or method
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: When you do `alert(this);` before that line, what do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the variable `this`. In the context you're using, `this` is probably referring to the jQuery object itself (that is, not the result set). Try this:

```
$.fn.fillSelect = function (url, map) {
    var $t = this;     // (this) is the jQuery result set

    $.getJSON( ... blah blah,

        $t.html(options.join(''));
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes you were absolutely right 'this' was referring to the jQuery object itself.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user331884 - if you find an answer helpful, vote it up and accept it by clicking on the links up to the left