# Handle and turn the json data into options selector with jQuery

Tags: jquery

So I have a `$.post`, that returns some `json_encode($array);`

`$array` is one dimensional, and it contains numbers: 2, 4, 6.

So now `data` is holding the json data, how can I loop through and make options to my `#time` selector? The `value=""` and display text should be the number from the array.

Comment: Refer this **[jQuery plugin question - populate select options with JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2831432/500725)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    $("<option />").text(val).val(val).appendTo("#time");
}​);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tmSqR/

---

**UPDATE.** Your data is not decoded from string format to JSON. Either add `dataType` property to `$.post`, or use `data = JSON.parse(data)` before making iteration.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tmSqR/1/

Comment: Nice answer!! Although i get many wrong options [ , 2 4 ] [ I want only the values of the json, its like it takes the whole incl syntax

Comment: @Karem I didn't actually understand what you meant.

Comment: Ok i tried this new but still nothing. When i do alert(data), i get [2,4] and if i output all val from the each() I get: ]4,2[

Comment: @Karem OK seems I got what you mean. Check the update in the answer.

Comment: Is `.val(val)` actually needed? The value of the `select` will be the text of an `option` if it has no `value` attribute. (I know it goes against the question as asked.)

Comment: @Amadan Agree, text data is enough. However, I left value just in case the OP decides to change the inner text.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to do this:

```
var s = $('select#time');
s.empty();
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  s.append($("<option />").text(value).val(key);
  //or 
  s.append($("<option value="key">value</option>"); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake, actually I needed to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Data returned by `json_encode($array)` from `PHP` is a string in javascript and needs to be converted to an object first to loop through it so use `$.parseJSON` before the loop begins

```
var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
$.each(obj, function(k, v) {
    $("<option />").text(v).val(v).appendTo("#time");
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/SQBZM/)